# Ctrl + Z, Shift + Z, and Alt + Z Not Working

Tags: keyboard, hardware-failure

I've had my computer for a while now, it's an ASUS TUF Gaming F15, and I've recently started to notice some keyboard issues. First of all, some of my keys were unresponsive. They sometimes don't register keypresses, and sometimes register a whole chain of keypresses even though I only pressed the key once. That isn't the issue I'm trying to resolve right now, however, I think it might help with diagnosing the problem I have at hand. What I'm trying to get an answer for is why pressing the Z key in combination with other keys such as Ctrl, Shift, and Alt doesn't work at all. They all do completely nothing. I've tested it on keyboard testers and they only register the Ctrl, Alt and Shift presses but not the Z press. I've tried to get an answer from several other places like google, reddit, etc, but I can't get an answer even remotely close to my problem. I'm getting kind of desperate now and I'm not sure if this is even the right place to post this, but please forgive me if I shouldn't post this kind of thing here, again, I'm getting real desperate.

Anyways, here are some things I tried:

- restarting the laptop
- updating drivers
- cleaning the keyboard (although I might not have cleaned it thoroughly enough)

Not really an edit but I only noticed this while writing this post:

- right Ctrl + Z works (and also every key that isn't close to Z, when pressed in combination, works)
- it **sometimes** works on its own, although very rarely

Also, for some more info:

- the faulty (unresponsive) keys are S, X, and Z
- I'm using a QWERTY layout

Comment: sounds like you need to replace the keyboard. most laptops are assembled so that it can be replaced (albeit it usually with some difficulty).

Comment: You might try to cleanup the keyboard - search the internet for instructions.

Comment: If you attach an external keyboard via USB, does that work properly?

Comment: @FrankThomas Ideally I want to avoid replacing the keyboard. I am aware that it is an option but that's my last resort if all else fails.

Comment: well, if it is the hardware failure that it sounds like it is, then there are no options other than to replace it, or live with it (perhaps using an external keyboard). I don't think there will be a software solution. but please answer Gantendo's question about the external.

Answer (score 1):

It's either a hardware failure or something has been split on teh keyboard which is shorting some tracks.

Try cleaning the keyboard - I have used this to fix many a keyboard from Vets (where the cats have walked on the desk and split drinks or even peed on them).

- Remove it, as best you can
- Inspect it physically and scrape off anything you spot with a plastic implement, gently
- Spray it copiously with CRC-556 (or WD-40), wipe it and let it dry.
- Reassemble

Comment: That would be WD-40 *Contact Cleaner* not regular WD-40… that would make a fair old mess;)